# Can not assign must be a instance. Django

Tags: python, django

I'm getting following error for my below mentioned code :

> Cannot assign "'1'": "OrderInfo.ordertype" must be a "Orders"
>   instance.

I know that it means `String` must to be an `instance` (maybe model object)

But, I have no idea why `String` is not allowed.

This is my code.

**Models.py** :

```
class OrderInfo(models.Model):
    post = models.OneToOneField(Post)
    ordertype = models.ForeignKey(Orders)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board)
    writer = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    writtendate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    editeddate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    text = RichTextField()
    hits = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Orders(models.Model):
    order = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Forms.py** :

```
class OrderEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    qs = Orders.objects.all()
    list = [(order.id, order.order) for order in qs]

    ##### list's value is [('1', 'A'), ('2', 'B')]

    ordertype = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=list))


    class Meta:
        model = OrderInfo
        fields = ('ordertype', 'company', 'position')

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('subject', 'text')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['subject'].required = True
```

**views.py**

```
def order_post_edit(request, board_id, post_id):    
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        orderform = OrderEditForm(request.POST, instance=post.orderinfo)

    if form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST['ordertype'])
        print(orderform.fields)
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.editeddate = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        orderform.save()

        return redirect('order_post', board_id=board_id, post_id=post.id)
else:
    form = PostForm(instance=post)
    orderform = OrderEditForm(instance=post.orderinfo)
return render(request, 'board/order/order_post_edit.html', {'form': form, 'orderform': orderform})
```

Comment: Looks like you explicitly made `ordertype` a charfield: `ordertype = forms.CharField`. Try changing that to `forms.IntegerField`

Comment: I did it but,, nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
ordertype = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=list))
```

When saving the object is trying to save the character selected for ordertype not the OrderType object instance for that id.
You could try:

```
if form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST['ordertype'])
        print(orderform.fields)
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.editeddate = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        orderinfo = orderform.save(commit=False)
        orderinfo.ordertype = Orders.objects.get(pk=orderinfo.ordertype)
        orderinfo.save()
```

There are probably better ways to get the data onto the form so that when selected it returns the object instance to you rather than the string of the id, but this is a quick solution.

Hope you get it resolved

Comment: What if I have ten fields? should I write all the code you mentioned for each field? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: By default form.save will return an object with all the fields set as to what was on the form, if you wanted to override any of them manually after this you can, but you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `ModelChoiceField`

In your `forms.py`

```
class OrderEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
  queryset = Orders.objects.all()
  ordertype = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=queryset, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

  class Meta:
    model = OrderInfo
    fields = ('ordertype', 'company', 'position')
```

If you use `Charfield` then validated value will return a string. but, django expects an instance. If we use `ModelChoiceField` then it will return an instance. So, we will not get error.
Otherway:

If you still want to use CharField then change the field name to `ordertype_id`

Comment: Changing the field name to `ordertype_id` in `class Meta` gives me `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (ordertype_id)`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue with Django 4.0 and was able to get it to work by returning the instance from the clean method.
The equivalent code for the above would be something akin to:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
   def clean_ordertype(self):
       order_type = self.cleaned_data.get('ordertype')
       if order_type:
            return OrderInfo.objects.get(pk=order_type)
```